# Can we put combobox, radio button, text field, table on text area?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I need this type of functionality.  Like in MS Word, we choose table in menu bar and then we draw in our sheet.

So how it can be done in Java?  I thought for sheet I can use `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 5):

No (to a `JTextArea`), but you should be able to do it using a `JTextPane`, see [`JTextPane#insertComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#insertComponent(java.awt.Component)) for more details

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();

            Document doc = tp.getDocument();

            try {
                tp.insertComponent(new JTextField("Hello world"));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
                tp.insertComponent(new JComboBox(new String[]{"Banana", "Apple", "Grape"}));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
                tp.insertComponent(new JRadioButton("Option A"));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
                tp.insertComponent(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(10, 5)));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
            } catch (BadLocationException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            add(new JScrollPane(tp));
        }

    }

}
```