# Incorporating HTML with JavaScript in my Java application

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm writing a small CBT Java application. The questions are read in from a local mySQL database. The application dynamically builds the question to include drop down lists and provides instant feedback on incorrect answers. Due to Java limitations, I had to resort to using HTML and JavaScript to construct these questions. Now I have a JEditorPane that I have a simple HTML page built in:

```
String html = "";

try
{
    html+="<html><head></head>";
    html+="<body onLoad='tester()'>";
        html+="<div id='stuff'>";
        html+="</div>";
    html+="</body></html>";

    htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
    htmlPane.setText(html);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Some problem has occured"+e.getMessage());
}
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to add the associated JavaScript to populate the "stuff" div. Further, I need to return results from the JavaScript to the calling Java method.

Comment: Why do you have Java limitations?  Javascript can't talk back to Java unless you have some kind of (eg. REST) service for it to pass back information to.

Comment: The questions are strings with drop down lists in them. There may be as many as 5 or 6 drop down lists that don't reoccur in the same location of each question. i was unable to layout JComboboxes dynamically so I resorted to the Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Nashorn (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) which is a JavaScript Engine in Java. 
You can run JavaScript from Java-code with the help of `ScriptEngineManager`.

But in most cases it is not the best design to mix several technologies especially different languages together. I'm pretty sure that you can implement this in pure Java.

You should be able to implement this using the `FlowLayout` in Swing (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).

A even better solution will be this;
[Can we put combobox, radio button, text field, table on text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358497/can-we-put-combobox-radio-button-text-field-table-on-text-area)

Comment: I'm just learning this language now, I had some instruction in college many years ago but never developed any GUI's. I've not been able to figure out how to embed a JComboBox within a string. There would be a variable number of JComboboxes within any given string at variable locations and as far as I've seen, the JCombobox components need to be at static locations.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want a Combobox in a text that floats with the text, is that right? (There is a distinction between the term `String` and the drawn Text on the GUI. The `String` is a datatype that is represented by i.e. a Label on the GUI)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Each question would be a variable number of words + combobox + variable number of words + combobox etc...

Comment: I have added some links to my answer that should show you how to do that