# Inserting a JList into an existing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a JFrame that looks like:
[image]

The user enters some command into JTextArea2 and the result is shown into JTextArea1.

Now, for a specific command entered I want to create and "insert" the JList somewhere inside the JTextArea1.

It would look like:
[image]

Here is a little bit of code to show how I initially place them. How could I do that?

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
textArea_1 = new JTextArea(25,112);
textArea_1.setEditable(false);
scroll_1 = new JScrollPane(textArea_1, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
add(scroll);
textArea_2 = new JTextArea(1,111);
scroll_2 = new JScrollPane(textArea_2, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
add(scroll_2);
```

Comment: Much depends and information not told and not shown. Please consider creating and posting your [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please read the links), and tell us what problems your current code is having. Quick suggestions though: be sure to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container after adding or removing components from it.

Comment: `I want to create and "insert" the JList somewhere inside the JTextArea1.` - you can't insert a JList inside a JTextArea. A JTextArea is used to display text not other Swing components.

Comment: Consider having a look at [`JTextPane#insertComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#insertComponent(java.awt.Component)) as an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358497/can-we-put-combobox-radio-button-text-field-table-on-text-area/28358512#28358512)