# JTextPane fails to show components when other text is added

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextpane

Two of my JButton's show up perfectly on my JTextPane when they are the only items on it. However, when I add more text to the JTextPane, the buttons seem to disappear from the JTextPane. For example:

```
possibleWordsPane.setText("");
possibleWordsPane.insertComponent(guessButton);
possibleWordsPane.insertComponent(botToggleButton);
possibleWordsPane.setText(possibleWordsPane.getText() + " \nTime left: " + time + '\n');
```

Only shows the buttons if the last line of the code is commented out or removed. **How can I get my two buttons to show alongside more text?**

Comment: You'll probably need to append the text after the components within the `Document`, maybe something similar to [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358497/can-we-put-combobox-radio-button-text-field-table-on-text-area/28358512#28358512)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!